# How to exit youtube-dl when streaming to mpv on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, youtube-dl, mpv

I often use the command `mpv <YouTube URL> --no-video` (FFmpeg may also be mandatory) to only stream audio when the video track is redundant, should commonly save over 99% of bandwidth. I run the command in PowerShell, but haven't yet found a way to exit without closing and restarting PowerShell — hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> result in `[input] No key binding found for key`... output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to close the process, I expect this to apply to all supported operating systems.

```
Exiting... (Quit)
```

Comment: FFmpeg outputs `[ffmpeg] tls: Failed to send close message` error on my system, I don't yet know if the message can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a PowerShell issue, this would happen no matter what script language you use for this effort, because this is youtube-dl causing this. The fact that you are doing this in PowerShell, does not mean PowerShell controls it. The force close, is killing off PowerShell, is stopping anything PowerShell started, regardless of what it started.

You could start an other PowerShell session and use...

```
Get-Process -Name youtube-dl | Stop-Process -Force
```

… or just open TaskManager to kill it.

It might be a better option for you to use PowerShell jobs to do what you are doing, which allows you to continue to use PowerShell as normal what the background job is running, and you can always look at the job state using the other *-Job cmdlets.

```
Get-Command -Name '*-Job'

# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Start-Job).Parameters
Get-help -Name Start-Job -Examples
Get-help -Name Start-Job -Full
Get-help -Name Start-Job -Online
```

Comment: I found out that `Q` is the hotkey to close youtube-dl — really obvious, but because the documentation is apparently lacking it's good that the information is now out there.

Comment: Doesn't at least `Ctrl` + `X` always kill the running process in the terminal on Linux? There's no Windows-alternative? I'll research PowerShell Jobs even though an answer for this particular question has been found.